# If/else statement does not evaluate properly shiny/R

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean, shiny

Working with shiny for R.

In my `ui.R` I have an element looking like this

```
radioButtons("startEnd",
    label = "Choose",
    choices = list("start" = 1,
    "end" = 2),
    selected = NA,
    inline = TRUE
)
```

In my `server.R` I have this

```
observeEvent(input$startEnd, {
    print(input$startEnd)
    if (!is.null(as.integer(input$startEnd)) == 1) {
            print("Gone in if")
    } else if (!is.null(as.integer(input$startEnd)) == 2) {
            print("Gone in else if")
    } else {
            print("Gone in nothing")
    }       
})
```

However, it always evaluates to `print("Gone in if")`. **BUT** my first `print(input$startZiel)` prints me the correct numbers, depending on what I clicked in the app.

Comment: `is.null() == 1` doesn't make much sense. Just use `is.null()`. `if` needs a boolean, and `is.null()` outputs a boolean. I have no idea what `is.null()==2` is trying to accomplish....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currently doing is converting `input$startEnd` to an integer, converting that integer to a boolean by negating its nullness, and then comparing that boolean to an integer. Because your numbers are not null, the boolean evaluates to TRUE which is equal to 1 and so the first condition always holds. I think what you want is in fact the following,

```
observeEvent(input$startEnd, {
print(input$startEnd)
asInt = as.integer(input$startEnd)
if(!is.null(asInt)) {
    if (asInt == 1) {
        print("Gone in if")
    } else if (asInt == 2) {
        print("Gone in else if")
    } else {
        print("Gone in nothing")
    }  
}
```

})